# Use of COPY TO in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using **COPY TO** in postgres to write a result of select statement in a file.
Here is my code:

```sql
    COPY (SELECT COALESCE(AG.AGOF_CODIGO, 0) ||E'\t'||
               cast('AGENDA' as varchar) ||E'\t'||
               regexp_replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(AG.AGOF_DESCRICAO, ' '))), E'[\\n\\r\\u2028]+', ' ', 'g' ) ||E'\t'||
               regexp_replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(AG.AGOF_DESCRICAO, ' '))), E'[\\n\\r\\u2028]+', ' ', 'g' ) ||E'\t'||
               COALESCE(TO_CHAR(AG.AGOF_DATAI, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSOF'), cast(' ' as varchar)) ||E'\t'||
               COALESCE(TO_CHAR(AG.AGOF_DATAF, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSOF'), cast(' ' as varchar)) ||E'\t'||
               (CASE WHEN AG.AGOF_SIT = '1' THEN (CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN AGOF_DATAI AND AGOF_DATAF THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) ELSE '0' END) ||E'\t'||
               STRING_AGG(CAST(PR.PRAG_PROD_CODIGO AS VARCHAR), ',') ||E'\t'||
               STRING_AGG(CAST(PR.PRAG_PRECOOFERTA AS VARCHAR), ',') as LAYOUT_1309
          FROM AGOF AG
         INNER JOIN PRAGOF PR ON PR.PRAG_AGOF_CODIGO = AG.AGOF_CODIGO 
         INNER JOIN PRODUTOS PRD ON PRD.PROD_CODIGO = PR.PRAG_PROD_CODIGO
         WHERE AG.AGOF_DIVULGACAO NOT IN ('a8')
         GROUP BY AG.AGOF_CODIGO, AG.AGOF_DESCRICAO, AG.AGOF_DESCRICAO, AG.AGOF_DATAI, AG.AGOF_DATAF, (CASE WHEN AG.AGOF_SIT = '1' THEN (CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN AGOF_DATAI AND AGOF_DATAF THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) ELSE '0' END)) TO '/home/postgres/RETAIL_PROMOTION_1309_000_AAAAMMDD.TSV' WITH CSV ESCAPE E'\t' ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

But, if the statement `STRING_AGG(CAST(PR.PRAG_PROD_CODIGO AS VARCHAR), ',')` return more than 1 result, separating by comma, the file as generated with double quotes in line. And i can not replace it with **nothing** here is an example of result:

```sql
5638004 AGENDA                                          224189
"5641004    AGENDA                                      78166,4076,69914,18998,20052,20389,24863,26995,91621,25927,3052,4998,5988,13226,27957,17470"
5658004 AGENDA                                          31313
"5668004    AGENDA                                      12478,2157,841547,14587,4589"
5678004 AGENDA                                          87125
5688004 AGENDA                                          224189
```

How to postgres don't put a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL *has* to escape a string that contains the separator character with quotes, otherwise the file wouldn't be valid CSV.

You have two choices:

1. Use a different character than `,` as second argument for `string_agg`.
2. Use a different `DELIMITER` character for `COPY` with the CSV format.

Then PostgreSQL won't have to add quotes.

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for the answer ... but: 
1 - My string character separator is ","
2 - My separator is TAB ...

Comment: Sorry, meant `DELIMITER` rather than separator.